# test if Xpath object is null/undefined

Tags: javascript, xpath

I am trying to pull xpath results from a variable that contains XML data.  Some of the data that I am trying to extract may or may not be present, so I am trying to get ahold of the error control.  Example:  my XML is stored in the variable `data`.  If I use the following code to get the text value of `Year`, and there is no data present, a console error is thrown `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null`.  This completely halts the JS and breaks my application.

```
var year = document.evaluate('//Article/Journal/JournalIssue/PubDate/Year', $(data).get(0), null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.innerText;
```

So, I decided to break it up to text if the XML data actually contains `Year`:

```
var yearobj = document.evaluate('//Article/Journal/JournalIssue/PubDate/Year', $(data).get(0), null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null)
if (yearobj !== null) {
     var year = yearobj.singleNodeValue.innerText;                     
}
else {
     year = '';
}
```

But `yearobj` is *not* coming up null, so the error persists.

I've also tried `if (typeof yearobj !== 'undefined') {` which didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But `yearobj` is *not* coming up `null`, so the error persists.

Maybe you've found a `yearobj` but `yearobj.singleNodeValue` isn't what you expect

Simplify it down to a check for truthiness of both `yearobj` and `singleNodeValue`

```
var year = '';
if (yearobj && yearobj.singleNodeValue) {
     year = yearobj.singleNodeValue.innerText;                     
}
```